# How to solve NPM ejs-mate - Error: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory

Tags: node.js, express, npm

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
"body-parser": "^1.19.0",
"connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
"consign": "^0.1.6",
"dotenv": "^8.2.0",
"ejs": "^2.4.1",
"ejs-mate": "^3.0.0",
"express": "^4.17.1",
"express-session": "^1.17.1",
"mongoose": "^5.9.25",
"passport": "^0.4.1",
"passport-local": "^1.0.0",
"passport-local-mongoose": "^6.0.1"
}
```

app.js

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(session({
secret: 'vw9CGbidDQuqJgq',
resave: false,
saveUninitialized: false
}));

app.engine('ejs', engine);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(flash());

consign().include('routes').into(app);
```

auth.js

```
module.exports = function(app){

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

app.route('/')
.get((req, res) => {
    res.render("index", { message: req.flash() }); 
})
.post(passport.authenticate("local", {
    successRedirect: "/users",
    failureRedirect: "/",
    failureFlash: "Username or Password invalid"
}));
```

index.ejs

```
<% layout('base-login') -%>
<div class="logo-login"></div>
<div class="panel">
<div class="panel-body box-login">
    <h3 class="title-login">Login</h3>
    <% if(message.success) { %>
        <div class="alert alert-success"><%= message.success %></div>
    <% } %>
    ...
```

I suspect the problem is when loading ejs-mate.
I would like to continue using it in order to better adjust the default layout.
This error appears only at the terminal, the rest works normal.
I tried in many ways to get around this error, but I couldn't.

Comment: According to the error it is trying to find a error.ejs in the views .Have u tried anywhere to render error.ejs?

Comment: Show!
That was it.
I had created the view for "page not found" and ended up forgetting to create the view for "error".
So, I created this other view now and then it stopped showing this error in the terminal.

Thanks for the help @prax.